# Selecting markers within a GeoJSON polygon (Leaflet)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a GeoJSON FeatureCollection object made up of several polygons and I would like to select the markers which lie within each polygon. The information contained within the markers is to be used to show average stats for each polygon.

I have seen some suggesting using http://turfjs.org/docs/#within or http://turfjs.org/docs/#inside.

Markers are simply in `L.Marker` form. I intend to use the `onEachFeature` function to have a popup for each polygon. Has anyone done this before and can recommend the best method?

Thanks